# How to find the least square solution of a linear system with a contraint in R

Tags: r, least-squares, optimization

M= matrix(c(1,0.5,0.4,0.6,1,0.6,0.3,0.7,1),3,3)
b=c(1,0.3,0.4)

I want to find x that:
1. all elements in x are non-negative
2. sum of square of (M*x-b) is minimum

How do I do it in R?

Edit-------------------------
So I found that there are two ways to do this:

The first way don't require and package, I created a function and wrote a short example:

```
# Define function 
solve_plus = function(K,O){
  n=length(O)
  ui = diag(n)
  ci = rep(0,n)

  func = function(x){t(K%*%x-O)%*%(K%*%x-O) }
  grad = function(x) {t(K)%*%(K%*%x-O)}

  init = rep(1/n,n)
  result=constrOptim(theta=init, grad=grad, f=func, ui=ui, ci=ci)
  return(result$par)
}

#An example
K= matrix(c(1,0.5,0.4,0.6,1,0.6,0.3,0.7,1),3,3) 
O=c(1,0.3,0.4)

S = solve_plus(K,O)
```

Or, you can use the lsqlincon function in the pracma package:

```
#An example
library(pracma)
K= matrix(c(1,0.5,0.4,0.6,1,0.6,0.3,0.7,1),3,3) 
O=c(1,0.3,0.4)
lsqlincon(K,O,lb = rep(0,3))
```

Comment: `constrOptim` in R will do it for you. I think this is more about a programming question.

Comment: If you've found the answer, you can post it in the Answer box below. Incidentally, upvotes for answer are worth twice as much as upvotes for questions, and you'll be able to accumulate both.

Comment: Agree with Sycorax: just post it as an answer.